# what is the problem in this destructuration? [['h1', 'text'].forEach( (case: [Component, assertion]) => { console.log(Component,assertion); });

Tags: javascript

I am new to array de-duplication, this has a sintaxis error, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
const txt = 'this is a tes';
[['h1', 'render an h1 tag'], ['p', 'render a p tag'], [Text, 'render Custom component']].forEach(
    (case: [Component, assertion]) => {
    console.log(Component,assertion);
});
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Could you describe the bug?

Comment: @Rojo sintaxis bug...Can you help me please?

Comment: If you are getting an error, [edit] your question and include your error, preferably as a blockquote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo, just remove "case:"

```
const txt = 'this is a tes';
[['h1', 'render an h1 tag'], ['p', 'render a p tag'], [Text, 'render Custom component']].forEach(
    ([Component, assertion]) => {
    console.log(Component,assertion);
});
```